# I want to call a method-1 in method-2 but with some amendments in method-1?

Tags: function, methods, overriding

```
public void method_1()
{
    code statement 1
    code statement 2
}
```

I would like to call method 1 without executing code statement 1, like this:

```
public void method_2()
{
   call method_1 without code statement 1
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please give more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't do that, you would need to edit `method_1()` to either have a parameter that would specify which segments are ran or use some method overloading to dictate which methods are run. Either way, you need a variable that `method_2()` can set and `method_1()` can check to see if code statement 1 should be ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parameter to method_1, on which you decide whether to execute statement 1 or not. Similar to this:

```
public void method_1(boolean withStatement1){
    if (withStatement1){
        code statement 1
    }
    code statement 2
}

public void method_2(){
    call method_1(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that is helpful indeed.

Comment: You can mark an answer as "accepted", if it worked for you. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: But suppose I want to run both functions then first function isn't working. it is throwing initialization error

Comment: You always have to call method_1 with a parameter now. If you want statement1 to be executed, call `method_1(true)`, else call `method_1(false)`.

Comment: Telling us the technologies you use would always be helpful upfront ;-) I don't know my way around selenium. Maybe try googling on how to use parameters in Selenium test cases. Or put the actual code in another method (e.g. `method_1_internal(boolean withStatement1)`), remove the parameter from your test case `method_1()` and just call `method_1_internal(true)` in your `method_1`.